# How can I detect if my upstart script is running?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, upstart

In pseudo code I'm trying to do something like the following

```
if myService is running
  restart myService
else
  start myService
```

How can I translate the above into a bash script or similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way is to use a PID file for storing the PID of the service. Then, you can use the PID stored in the PID file to see if the service is already running or not.

Take a look at the various scripts under the `/etc/init.d` directory and see how they use the PID file. Also take a look under `/var/run` in most Linux systems to see where the PID files are stored.

You can do something like this which is a generic way of handling this for all Bourne shell type shells:

```
# Does the PID file exist?

if [ -f "$PID_FILE" ]
then
    # PID File does exist. Is that process still running?
    if ps -p `cat $PID_FILE` > /dev/null 2&1
    then

       # Process is running. Do a restart
       /etc/init.d/myService restart
       cat $! > $PID_FILE
    else
       # Process isn't' running. Do a start
       /etc/init.d/myService start
       cat $! > $PID_FILE
else
   # No PID file to begin with, do a restart
   /etc/init.d/myService restart
   cat $! > $PID_FILE
fi
```

However, on Linux, you can take advantage of [pgrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep):

```
if pgrep myService > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    restart service
else
    start service
fi
```

Note how you do not use any braces. The `if` statement operates on the exit status of the `pgrep` command. I'm outputting both STDOUT and STDERR to /dev/null because I don't want to print them. I just want the exit status of the `pgrep` command itself.

**READ THE [MANPAGE](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) ON PGREP**

There are quite a few options. For example, you might want to use `-x` to prevent unintended matches, or you might have to use `-f` to match on the full command line used to start the service.

Answer (score 0):

If you see **myService** when you run a **ps aux**, then you could simply do this in bash (edited to use pgrep, as jordanm suggested):

```
if [ $(pgrep myService) ]; then
    restart myService;
else
    start myService;
fi
```

Comment: The [ ] and the $() is unnecessary. `pgrep` is also better suited.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited to use pgrep. I only could not remove the $().

Comment: `if pgrep myService >/dev/null; then ...`. 'if' tests the exit status of a command. `[` is an alias for `test`, which is a command, not part of the if syntax.